# How do i copy the {col:datatype} from reference dataframe and apply to the main dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have two data frames with same column names but some columns may have different datatypes. How do i copy the {col:datatype} from reference dataframe  and apply to the main dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
    'C': [1.1, '1.0', '1.3', 2, 5] }) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'A': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], 
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
    'C': [1.1, '1.0', '1.3', 2, 5] }) 
dtypes =df1.dtypes.astype(str).to_dict() #take the columns and its datatypes from reference df
df2 = df2.astype({k:v for k,v in dtypes.items()})# apply to main df
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the columns and apply the type.

But you may need to add some error handling as `astype` requires the column to be castable to the provided type. So if you try to `.astype(int)` a column where a value is `'c'`, you can't.  Generally you would use the more flexible `pd.to_numeric` or `pd.to_datetime` methods that can coerce bad values to `NaN` and infer the dtype (i.e. float vs. int for pd.to_numeric).

```
for col in df2.columns:
    try:
        df2[col] = df2[col].astype(dtypes[col])
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this,

```
enter code here
for i in df1.columns:
    df2[i]=df2[i].astype(df1[i].dtype)
```